# Django dynamic url parameter names

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

Basically trying to do

```
    {%  url dynamic_url_name dynamic_parameter_name=dynamic_parameter_value %}
```

Tried the simplest approach of

```html
<a href="{% url belongs_to belongs_to_url_arg=entry|getattribute:belongs_to_url_arg_value %}">{{entry}}</a>
```

```
    {% include 'mainsite/children/title_template.html' with
        the_title=title_text
        is_title_page=True
        entries_of="title"
        belongs_to="profile"
        belongs_to_url_arg="user"
        belongs_to_url_arg_value="author"
    %}
```

But unfortunately this resulted in utter failure of [image]

From this I can tell that parameters can't be context variables, so what I can try to do next is to simply unpack a dictionary as I would do inside python with something like

```
{% url **{dynamic_parameter_name:dynamic_parameter_value} %}
```

But I have no idea if it is possible inside django templates, and if possible how?

---

My urls look like

```
re_path(r'^title/(?P<title_text>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', TitlePage.as_view(), name='title')
re_path(r'^user/(?P<user>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', ProfilePage.as_view() ,name='profile')
```

And I the url is choosen either by a context variable or in an include tag, hence it is a variable.

```
{% url url_variable xxx=value %}
```

Now, url_variable is already a part of django, url tag accepts variable as it's first argument. But the `xxx` is not always the same, rather it changes according to `url_variable`, in this particular case; if `url_variable` is title, I want `xxx` to be `title_text` and if it is profile I want it to be `user`.
The parameter name is held in `belongs_to`, so if this was a regular python function, I could've simply done

```
url(url_variable, **{belongs_to: value})
```

and it would've unpacked it with the correct parameter name. So I need some kind of equivalency of this in template processor

Comment: You don't want URL pattern elements at all. You want querystrings, eg `/dynamic_url/?belongs_to=foo&the_title=bar` etc.

Comment: No because there are different html involved inside the `profile` and `title` pages which I'm trying to link to. the get parameters are indeed used for other filtering but I have 3 main model `user` `title` `entry` which all have their own respective urls and templates. Entry model is shown in every single one of them, but the footer changes according to both base url and get parameters.

Comment: I don't see why that contradicts what I said at all.

Comment: Wouldn't it be absurd to have `/title/?title=some-title` instead of `/title/some-title/` or am I not getting it

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying at all. Why would you duplicate "title"? What do you want your *full* URL to look like? (And what does that include tag have to do with anything?)

Comment: It shows that I am trying to put the parameter name as an argument too,

`title` view's url takes a parameter named title and `profile` view's' take a parameter named user, and they both show the entries of the respected title or user, so I want to have a url tag in template that if I reverse profile(which is decided in belongs_to), it uses `user="some_value"` and if I reverse title it uses `title="some_value"` as its keyword argument and value. I'm also updating the question to add a bit more information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overcomplicating things. You haven't shown your views themselves, but I can't see why they couldn't all take a commonly-named parameter - say, `param` - that does the specific work. So the URLs could be:

```
re_path(r'^title/(?P<param>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', TitlePage.as_view(), name='title')
re_path(r'^user/(?P<param>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', ProfilePage.as_view() ,name='profile')
```

and now you can do

```
{% url dynamic_url_name param=dynamic_parameter_value %}
```

Comment: If I need to reverse more than 4-5 urls like this, I think it would be a bit unreadable but I guess this is the best approach so far, upsetting that django templates don't have such a simple feature like unpacking maps in tag kwargs.

Answer (score 0):

`**kwargs` are not specifically supported as a parameter for the `{% url %}` tag, but there are a few workwarounds.

If you have a path in urlpatterns defined as:

```
path('myurl/<str:some>/<str:thing>', name='myurl')
```

Then you could have a `filetoinclude.html`:

```
<a href="{% url urlname some thing %}">My Url</a>
```

And then in your `main.html`:

```
{% include 'filetoinclude.html' with urlname='myurl' some="aaa" thing="bbb" %}
```

And when you render you will have something like:

```
<a href="localhost:8000/myurl/aaa/bbb">My Url</a>
```

But obviously the issue is that maybe you want to address specific parameters of the URL when you reverse it. For this reason you could create a templatetag like:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def dynamic_url(urlname, **kwargs):
    return reverse(urlname, kwargs=kwargs)
```

and then in your `filetoinclude.html` you could do:

```
{% load url_extended %}
{% dynamic_url urlname some=some thing=thing %}
```

which will yield the same URL as before.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, 

`{% dynamic_url urlname some(1)=some(2) thing=thing %}`

`some(1)` is going to be the literal `"some"` in that case as well and is not going to be rendered as a value, hence I still need to hardcode the parameter name. 
What I want is to be able to refer
`path('myurl/<str:some>/<str:thing>', name='myurl')`
`path('myurl/<str:some2>/<str:thing2>', name='myurl2')`

`some` and `some2` without hardcoding them rather with a context variable named `some_id` and do

`{% url urlname some_id=some thing_id=thing %}`

which still is impossible in your version.

Comment: are the number of parameters varying from one url to another? If not why not just pass them like in the first example from my answer?

Comment: There are urls with optional arguments so what I'm looking is a universal way to handle these, right know I'm just hacking my way out but it is disturbing

Comment: @IşıkKaplan could you tell me more about your case ? Where do you get the parameters from and why would you need to reverse URL's like that?

Comment: @IşıkKaplan any news?

Comment: I have footer where I use almost everywhere in the templates with include, which needs to have different view's urls in it, footer for entry is going to send to author page while footer for trophies is gonna send to trophy details page for instance.

So the reversed url in the footer changes(which can be done by sending a context variable) and the url parameters also should change because author page's url takes a `user` while trophy_detail page takes `trophy`.